# Can I reproduce video in 1440×1080 12M MP4 on a Full HD TV?

Tags: video, mp4, avchd

I am interesting in shooting some amatorial videos (family) with a digital camera.

At the moment my camera support AVCHD and MP4.

I found AVCHD less compatible and more time consuming to process so I was thinking if MP4 would be a more convenient options.

In that format my digital camera shoot at 1440×1080 12M MP4

I would like to know:

- Can I reproduce video on a FULL HD TV (1920x1080) recorded with 1440×1080 12M MP4?
- Would you suggest AVCHD instead for my use scenario?

Her some technical details of my camera:

http://docs.esupport.sony.com/dvimag/DSCRX100_guide/en/contents/04/03/02/02.html

http://www.sony.jp/products/overseas/contents/pickup/english/110324_promotion/DSC-TX100_Full_HD/

http://www.dpreview.com/reviews/sony-cybershot-dsc-rx100-m2/5

Comment: Maybe related: http://www.frankschrader.us/2013/05/pixel-aspect-ratio-video-resolution-of-1440x1080-considered-a-widescreen-format-169/

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention either how (or IF?) you are editing anything here, or what forms of storage, distribution, archiving, etc you anticipate?

You are probably correct that MP4 is a more compatible distribution format, but distribution format does not necessarily have to be identical with recording and editing format.

I would not anticipate any issue with displaying a 1440×1080 frame on a 1920x1080 screen. Modern digital displays typically handle scaling (UP or DOWN) pretty seamlessly.  In any case, shouldn't it be easy to actually try it for yourself?  No amount of anonymous advice from the internet beats actual first-hand experiment.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I would like to ask you... By scaling do you mean that the resolution 1440x1080 as a different aspect ratio for pixel dimensions. Example square vs rectangle? Thanks for your time on this.

Comment: The digital video contains "meta information" about the video so that different screens can display it properly.  Note that 1440x1080 is the old 4x3 frame standard, and not the modern 16x9 frame.